# Transferring a SQL Database on AWS

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012, amazon-rds

We have a SQL Server 2005 database on our local server.

Here it is (ofc i've to repeat the proceder for the other databases):

[image: Here it is:]

I've to transfer it to our SQL server 2012 instance on Amazon RDS.

I right clicked the database and selected Generate Scripts - All tables - Copy Schema and Data and saved everything as a sql file

[image]

At this point I attempted to use the SQL Azure MW v5.15 (in a question here I saw that it works with AWS too, way to go Microsoft!) to transfer the database on AWS.
However it crashes.
No problem, I try to use SQL Management studio to import the file but as soon the RAM consumed by the program reaches 1gb (as you can see that DB is 3,4gb) BOOM - out of memory error!
What should I do now?

Comment: Solved by doing this:
1) Create a SQL Server Express instance on a EC2 Machine
2) Import the .bak database files
3) Import the databases in RDS via the Import tool

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to do part-by-part of your creation. I'd faced that problem some time before, my scripts reaches like 4 GB, only with the schemas, tables, etc. So, I think you should first of all, generate your scripts of creating schemas, users and logins. After that, tables, views and procedures. Then, another objects, like jobs, functions... To conclude, all the data you have, you should export to the RDS through the IMPORT/EXPORT Wizard in SSMS.
I've followed that steps and it worked for me.

Good luck!

Comment: I thinked about splitting every sql file in 5-6 parts as well :)
Thank god someone had my same idea and worked!
However i'm trying to do something different now: i'll upload the .bak files to EC2, install SQL Server, import them and use AWS-DMS to transfer everything to RDS :) 
Let's see how it will work out :)

Comment: It won't work. RDS won't let you transfer that data... The only way I've found to do that, is the way I've commented. Btw, If you find anything, please, share with us.

Comment: Read above for how i did it :D